# pass a value from gsp to controller

Tags: grails, controller, gsp

I have something like this

```
<g:each in="${category}" status="i" var="cat">
   <li class="demo_li"><g:link action="listGame"><img id= "icon" src="${resource(dir: 'icons', file: "${cat.icon}")}"><div>${cat.categoryName}</div></g:link></li>
```

I want to pass the value of ${cat.categoryName} to the controller if i click on it
how do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Grails [g:link](https://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/ref/Tags/link.html) tag has a `params` attribute you can use to pass parameters to a controller action. The `params` is a `Map`. Lets say you name the parameter *categoryName*. You'd specify it like this:

```
<g:link action="listGame" params="${[categoryName: cat.categoryName]}">..</g:link>
```

In your controller's `listGame()` action you can access the parameter like this: `params.categoryName`

Comment: I used that and have this on my controller

def currentCategory = params.categoryName
  [currentCategory:currentCategory]


and ony my view ${currentCategory} doesn't do anything, why is that?

Comment: To access  currentCategory within the view you need to add it to the model.

Comment: what do you mean add it to the model? I already have a model of the category